Avalonia TreeView TreeDataTemplate not working as expected
I'm using this TreeDataTemplate for my treeview where I select the TreeDataTemplate via a datatemplate selector (IDataTemplate). And setting the Itemssource in the TreeDataTemplate declaration. But even if I have some items in it, the treeviewitem tooglebutton (Expander) won't show.
Can someone tell me why?
    <TreeDataTemplate x:Key="databasecollectiontreetemplate" DataType="{x:Type sharedvm:DatabaseCollectionViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection.Values}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="header"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Foreground="{Binding Connected, Converter={StaticResource connectionconverter}}"/>
             <Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding CreateElementCommand}" Content="{Binding CreateElementCommand}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource toolcommandtemplate}" />
        </Grid>
    </TreeDataTemplate>

